# How can I append a pandas Series to a DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I realize this question has been asked before, but none of those seem to work for me. I have a series called `state` that looks like:

```
cash          17378.787327
num_shares      895.000000
cost_basis      102.153149
open_price      106.300003
close_10        108.889999
close_9         109.790001
close_8         109.209999
close_7         108.230003
close_6         109.330002
close_5         108.080002
close_4         106.910004
close_3         106.419998
close_2         104.410004
close_1         106.650002
dtype: float64
```

I want to append it to a `DataFrame`, so I have:

```
X = pd.DataFrame()
X.append(state)
```

But this gives an error `TypeError: Can only append a Series if ignore_index=True or if the Series has a name`, so I try:

```
X.append(state, ignore_index=True)
```

This doesn't actually append anything to `X`:

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: []
```

What am I doing incorrectly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I ended up doing:

```
X = X.append([state], ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: Just what I was looking for

Comment: As of pandas 2.0, `append` (previously deprecated) was removed https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/whatsnew/v2.0.0.html#removal-of-prior-version-deprecations-changes. Credit to this comment I found on SO https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75956209/error-dataframe-object-has-no-attribute-append/75956237#75956237

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use `X['state'] = state`.

Example:

```
import pandas as pd
dic = {'Name': ['Braund, Mr. Oven Harris',
                'Allen, Mr William Henry',
                'Bonnell, Miss. Elizabeth'],
       'Sex': ['male', 'male', 'female']
      }    
df = pd.DataFrame(dic)
ages = pd.Series([22, 35, 58], name='Age')
df['Age'] = ages
```

---

```
                       Name     Sex  Age
0   Braund, Mr. Oven Harris    male   22
1   Allen, Mr William Henry    male   35
2  Bonnell, Miss. Elizabeth  female   58
```

Comment: I want each column in `state` to be a column in `X`

Comment: i dont understand what you are saying considering a pandas series is one column

Comment: The `Series` is one column, but has labels (`cash`, etc). I want those labels to be columns of the `DataFrame`

Comment: As the selected answer is based on the now deprecated `DataFrame.append`, this seems to be the new best answer. With your permission I'm adding an example in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

more than one column is a data frame, so you can try this:

```
X=pd.concat([X,state], axis=1)
```

Comment: This flips it. `[14 rows x 30 columns]`. I need it to be 14 columns

Comment: so you mean X has the same 14 columns as State?

Answer (score 0):

Using

```
state.name=0
X = pd.DataFrame()
X.append(state)
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want both the labels and the values to be appended to the dataframe. You need to reset the `Series index`

`state.reset_index()`